# Orchard Get Default Tenant scoop

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'm trying to access an Event Workflow which belongs to the Default Tenant in the setup of a new Tenant .

so in SetupService (Orchard.Setup) i'm calling the shell :

```
        var shellContext = _orchardHost.GetShellContext(_shellSettingsManager.LoadSettings().Where(x => x.Name == "Default").FirstOrDefault());
        using (var _environment = shellContext.LifetimeScope.Resolve<IWorkContextAccessor>().CreateWorkContextScope())
        {
            var Subscriber = environment.Resolve<ISetupCompletEventHandler>();
            Subscriber.SetupCompleted(new TenantContext
            {
                Name = context.SiteName,
                Email = context.SiteEmail,
                user = user
            });
        }
```

my Event :

```
public class WorkflowSetupEventHandler : ISetupCompletEventHandler
{
    private readonly IWorkflowManager _workflowManager;
    public WorkflowSetupEventHandler(IWorkflowManager workflowManager)
    {
        _workflowManager = workflowManager;
    }

    public void SetupCompleted(TenantContext context)
    {
        _workflowManager.TriggerEvent("SetupCompleted",
                         context.user,
                         () => new Dictionary<string, object> {
                                         {"Email", context.Email},
                                         {"Name", context.Name}
                         });
    }
}
```

for some reason the SetupCompleted is never fired .

am i missing soemthing ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was i'm trying to get the Default Tenant while the "Default" Tenant did not exist yet his state was not `running` on the `shellsettings`